# Is the combined flair imagerator broken?

Tags: support, flair, combined-flair

In the long tradition of posts of this type, I call to the users of SE: is your rectangle running? If so, can you catch it?

Seriously though, is the combined flair busted again? I can't see mine:

[image: profile for Trevor Alexander on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Comment: The image is not showing for me, Chrome and Safari iOS.

Comment: No repro here, but I know some people have been having problems with stackexchange.com and flair pictures.

Comment: Reproduced (I've been having this problem as mentioned by @hichris123 for a few days now).

Comment: The image is showing for me in Safari on my iPhone 5S with iOS 8.1.

Comment: The flair is cached individually on each server, so whether you hit the corrupted cache depends on the server you hit. This is why some people can repro and some can't. One way or another, the caches are cleared weekly, so this will resolve itself.

Comment: I see yours, i see mine. Chrome on Ubuntu.

Comment: This is a pretty recursive thread. Seems to have resolved on my end.

Comment: Is this still an issue for you? I've cleared out the cache from one of our servers that seems to have been problematic in this respect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I call to the users of SE: is your rectangle running?

Yes, I can see my rectangle, hope you can see it too:

[image: my flair]

> If so, can you catch it?

Catching yours on Chrome and IE (64-bit Windows 7):
[image: OP's flair]

Comment: Accepted for being the most recursive post in the list. :D

Answer (score 6):

- Firefox 33.0:

  [image]
- Chrome 30.0.1599.114:

  [image]
- Opera 12.16:

  [image]

All browsers were running on 64bit Debian testing.

Comment: I verified in: Windows 7 64 with IE 11.0.9600.17358, Chrome 38.0.2125.111 m, Firefox 33.1. Cyanogenmod 11-2014100--SNAPSHOT-M11-jflte with Firefox 33.1, Chrome 38.0.2125.114 and default browser. Galaxy S4 default Android 4.4.2 Chrome 38.0.2125.114, Firefox 33.0, and the default browser. Ubuntu 14.04 64 with Firefox 33.0, Chromium 38.0.2125.111, and Chrome 38.0.2125.111. BlackBerry 9000 v5.0.0.1067 default browser. The only thing I couldn't see the image in was Lynx 2.8.8dev.9, but a link to the profile did appear.

Comment: I have the same issue on Chrome on my iPad. It looks like it depends on which server we're connecting to or which server is serving that flair. For example, I can see infiniterecursion's flair fine but not the others.

Comment: @terdon I'm having exact same problem now, Combined flair is broken/not-showing in the two systems I'm using at the moment(both running Fedora 21 64bit, Firefox latest rpm).

Answer (score 5):

[image: Rectangle working.]

Answer (score 5):

Works for me in Chrome  38.0.2125.111 m:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Works on my machine, even with JavaScript disabled. Not that it matters.

[image]

Comment: Btw, why flair doesn't have its colors inverted on your screenshot?

Comment: @nicael The inversion happens on CSS, so all pictures retain their appearance. Sure would be ugly otherwise.

Comment: Another question: Why do you use color inversion at all?

Comment: @nicael Well, [my workstation](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/22091?m=19649417#19649417) is located where I don't get sunlight in the room, and at night I intentionally leave the lights dim, and so white screens are really discomforting for me. So I use inverse colors.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a recurring thing, but it's broken at this time.  Reviewing this thread it appears that back in the time frame of the original question the immediate issue might have been different and had something to do with certain browsers.  But at this time it certainly isn't the browsers or associated browser cache.  The combined flair is actually broken.  All the other flairs on the flair page works.  However, the combined flair doesn't.

It doesn't work on my default browser on Ubuntu, Google Chrome.

Other browsers tried:

- Chromium
- (ubuntu)
- Firefox (Ubuntu)
- Internet Explorer (Windows 7)

The other flairs on this page: https://askubuntu.com/users/29012/l-d-james/flair works on all my machines and all my browsers.

I don't know how long it has been down, but I have noticed it for full day.

I don't see any input in this question from the site administrators.  Hopefully someone will add some input and definition to what is happening and refer to a reporting mechanism for having it addressed.  I understand having network and server issues that happens from time to time.  But if it's going to be days or weeks in having it addressed, I'd prefer to know so that I can do something about the anesthetics of my production website.