# Flair buttons suddenly broken?

Tags: support, flair, combined-flair

For the last year or so, I've been using this link to display my combined flair `https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1144664.png`

As of yesterday (?) that image link is broken and redirects to https://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/flair/1144664.png.

My Stack **Overflow** flair still works - https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1127699.png

I can see that other people's Combined Flair still works e.g. https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1.png

According to the [Flair page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair), my link is correct - so what's going on?

Comment: The cached flair on the specific web server you are hitting must be corrupt.

Comment: I've cleaned up the caches on the specific server you were hitting - how do things look like now?

Comment: Now appears fine, although my browser has cached the redirect. Thanks for the swift fix :-)

Comment: ...and it appears to be broken again - https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1144664.png?theme=dark

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by Oded [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243367/is-the-combined-flair-imagerator-broken/243372#comment795422_243367):

> The flair is cached individually on each server, so whether you hit the corrupted cache depends on the server you hit. This is why some people can repro and some can't. One way or another, the caches are cleared weekly, so this will resolve itself.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. May I humbly suggest a more rapid refresh rate - or a proactive monitoring of cache misses?

Comment: Indeed. On my blog, it's currently telling me I don't have over 200 rept on any linked accounts, whereas I have over 1k on two sites and over 200 on another 4. If this is a caching problem, then the caching solution could do with some optimisation :)